# no me acepta el disabled en angular

Tags: angular, angular7

tengo una tabla paginada como muestro en el codigo pero estoy intentando deshabilitar la opcion "Custodiar" de acuerdo al valor que vaya tomando la variable "Deshabilitar"

```
              <table class="table table-striped table-no-bordered table-hover" id="tbGarantia" style="width:100%"  >
                <tfoot>
                  <tr>
                    <th class="text-center">{{ HeaderGarantia[0] }}</th>
                    <th class="text-center">{{ HeaderGarantia[1] }}</th>
                    <th class="text-center">{{ HeaderGarantia[2] }}</th>
                    <th class="text-center">{{ HeaderGarantia[3] }}</th>
                    <th class="text-center">{{ HeaderGarantia[4] }}</th>
                    <th class="text-center">{{ HeaderGarantia[5] }}</th>
                    <th class="text-center">{{ HeaderGarantia[6] }}</th>
                    <th class="text-center">{{ HeaderGarantia[7] }}</th>

                  </tr>
                </tfoot>
                <tbody>
                  <tr *ngFor="let row of ListarGarantia" [ngClass]="{'info': row.estado_Vigencia=== 'GARANTIA RENOVADA'}">

                    <td class="text-center " style="font-weight:bold">{{row.numero_Garantia}}</td>
                    <td class="text-center ">{{row.objeto_Garantia}}</td>
                    <td class="text-center">{{row.fecha_Inicio | date:'dd/MM/yyyy'}}</td>
                    <td class="text-center">{{row.fecha_Vencimiento | date:'dd/MM/yyyy'}}</td>
                    <td class="text-center">{{row.asunto_Vigencia}}</td>
                    <td class="text-center" [ngClass]="{' text-success' : row.estado_Vigencia=== 'VIGENTE','text-danger' : row.estado_Vigencia === 'VIGENCIA CONCLUIDA','text-warning  ' : row.estado_Vigencia === 'POR VENCER'}">{{row.estado_Vigencia}}</td>
                    <td class="text-center">{{row.custodio}}</td>
                    <td class="text-center" >

                      <ng-container  [disabled]="Deshabilitar" >
                        <a rel="tooltip" title="Custodiar" class="btn  btn-success btn-simple btn-xs" [routerLink]="['ingresoGarantia', row.id_Garantia, row.numero_Garantia]" >
                          <i class="fa fa-archive"></i>
                        </a>
                      </ng-container>                      
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
```

pero no me acepta usar el disabled en esa etiqueta habra alguna otra manera de hacerlo

Comment: Podrias compartirnos donde tenes definida la variable seteada y como toma los valores?

Comment: el atributo `disabled` es para `input, textarea, select, button, option` no para otras etiquetas. Aquí tienes la documentación https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/disabled. Puedes explicar lo que quieres hacer? Quieres que no se pueda clicar el link?

Comment: asi es lo que quiero hacer es que se deshabilite dependiendo que valor tome la variable "Deshabilitar"

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que des habilitarlo por css, puedes poner un ngclass con la condición o con la clase quemada

Quemada

```
<a class="isDisabled" href="https://unfetteredthoughts.net">Disabled Link</a>
```

Ngclass

```
<a [ngClass]="{ isDisabled: CONDICION }" href="">Disabled Link</a>
```

En el apartado de css agregas la clase

```
.isDisabled {
  pointer-events: none;
  cursor: not-allowed;
}

.isDisabled:hover {
  cursor: not-allowed;
}
```

Para tu ejemplo en concreto

```
<div [ngClass]="{ isDisabled: Deshabilitar }">
  <a  rel="tooltip" title="Custodiar" class="btn  btn-success btn-simple btn-xs" [routerLink]="['ingresoGarantia', row.id_Garantia, row.numero_Garantia]" >
    <i class="fa fa-archive"></i>
  </a>
</div>
```

o si lo prefieres sobre el propio enlace

```
<a [ngClass]="{ isDisabled: Deshabilitar }" rel="tooltip" title="Custodiar" class="btn  btn-success btn-simple btn-xs" [routerLink]="['ingresoGarantia', row.id_Garantia, row.numero_Garantia]" >
  <i class="fa fa-archive"></i>
</a>
```

Te recomiendo esta documentación:
https://css-tricks.com/how-to-disable-links/